# Uploading a Blob using HTTP conditional headers

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

I'm using [Google Cloud Python API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) to upload blobs into buckets, which is working just fine.
However, for my specific use case, I need to prevent files from being overwritten. Instead of doing it in two go's (1st request to check if the file exists, 2nd upload the blob), I would much prefer to do it in one shot.
Apparently this can be done by using some conditional [HTTP headers, e.g. `If-None-Match: '*'`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#ifnonematch).

Regretfully, the [Google Cloud Python API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) doesn't seem to allow for any custom headers.

Any ideas on how I could go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround in [GoogleCloudPlatform Issues log in GitHub - #4490](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/4490):

> I am currently hacking around this by replacing `google.cloud.storage.blob._MULTIPART_URL_TEMPLATE` and `google.cloud.storage.blob._RESUMABLE_URL_TEMPLATE` with versions that have the precondition I require, e.g.
>
> ```
> from google.cloud import storage as gcs
>
> gcs.blob._MULTIPART_URL_TEMPLATE = (
>     f'{gcs.blob._MULTIPART_URL_TEMPLATE}&ifGenerationMatch=0'
> )
> gcs.blob._RESUMABLE_URL_TEMPLATE = (
>     f'{gcs.blob._RESUMABLE_URL_TEMPLATE}&ifGenerationMatch=0'
> )
> ```

This is marked as a feature request. Hopefully it'll be added in the near future.

Comment: As you found a workaround for this feature request, please accept the answer.